# htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, stdClass given

Tags: laravel-livewire

I ma getting the error on the script $bank that must be of type string. and on my controller I have defined it as a string

```
<select wire:model="bank" name="bank" class="form-select">
                                @foreach($banks as $bank)
                                <option value="'{{$bank->name}}'">{{$bank->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
```

This is the script where am getting the error when emitted htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, stdClass given

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        Livewire.on('changeModels', () => {
            // Code Here
            toggleViews({{$bank}})
            //    $('.bank-mode').removeClass('d-none').siblings('.driver-pay-method').addClass('d-none')//

        })
    }
</script>
```

Contoller I have defined $bank variable as string.

```
public String $bank="";

public function updatedBank($value)
{
    $this->bank =$value;
    $this->emit('changeModels');
}
```

Comment: You're looping the `$banks` property on the view, but this property it's not available on your controller. Can you edit your question and add the `$banks` to your controller?

Answer (score 1):

You're looping the `$banks` variable into `$bank`. By doing this, you're overwriting the `$bank` variable in your blade view, from the string that you expect to the last available bank object. If you change the variable name, then it should function:

```html
<select wire:model="bank" name="bank" class="form-select">
    @foreach($banks as $bankModel)
        <option value="{{$bankModel->name}}">
            {{$bankModel->name}}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```